# Build error with Clang + msm-3.18 Kernel Android Q

Tags: clang, android-source, android-kernel

i tried to build android  Kernel msm-3.18 with Clang along with aosp 10 and im getting build error related to Linker

CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
clang-9: error: unable to execute command: Executable "ld" doesn't exist!
clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:91: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1

attaching the snapshot and make command

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/82863729/115356430-473bab00-a1d9-11eb-962d-3f157d022c20.jpeg

[Error LOG] (https://pastebin.com/K5kXM606)`logs`

please suggest how to fix this error

Comment: your source code is not compatible with clang. use gcc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this error, and find out where the `ld` command path define.

```
make[1]: *** [/data/home/prdn273053/aosp_10/kernel/msm-3.18/Makefile:462: scripts_basic] Error 2
```

I think it will be help.